# Close Datetime picker calendar after pick time in bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I have added datetimepicker but after picking date and time calendar not hiding or closing automatically. So how can I hide or close the calandar when time. I mean when finally select `AM` or `PM` then the calendar will hide. Here is my code blew.

```js
    $(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker({   
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A', // A
        ////format: 'MM/DD/YYYY', // A
        icons: {
            time: "fa fa-clock",
            date: "fa fa-calendar",
            up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
            down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
        }
    }).on('changeDate', function (e) {
        $(this).datetimepicker('hide');
    });
```

```html
<!-- 
  You should be able to change the version numbers below to match the versions you're using in your app. 
  You will likely need to remove the integrity attributes if you do. 
-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input type="text" class="datetimepicker">
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a `<script` tag pointing to the DateTimePicker component you are using. There are several out there, and without knowing which one it is, we can't help you.